# bin/magento cron:install not writing to crontab

Tags: magento2, cron

I have ran **bin/magento cron:install** and then show

> Crontab has been generated and saved

but I run **crontab -l**, nothing was written into cron, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue cron is working fine in local but not working in server. so I used the below method to test cron is working or not.

- Magento creates three log files, which are `var/log/magento.cron.log`, `var/log/update.cron.log` and `var/log/setup.cron.log.` You can watch these log files.
- You should see some input with the following SQL query: `select * from cron_schedule.` It keeps track of each cron job, when it is run, when it is finished if it is finished.
- You can run the following commands on your command line, and see if they are running properly without any error.

  ```
  /usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule"
  /usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/update/cron.php
  /usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/bin/magento setup:cron:run
  ```

For more reference see this doc [Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

I hope it helps!

Comment: i've errors in magento.cron.log SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `cron_schedule` SET `job_code` = ?, `status` = ?, `messages` = ?, `created_at` = '2017-10-31 17:30:36', `scheduled_at` = '2017-10-31 17:37:00', `executed_at` = ?, `finished_at` = ? WHERE (schedule_id='1028796')  , do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I have no idea about this error but i will share you if i found something.